# VBA - multiple string variables - avoid referencing to them many times

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an .xlsm web scraping template. I want it to stay very flexible. Perfectly I would like to declare all string variables, have them listed in an array and be able to assign each variable from an array VbNullstring value when needed by typying variable name only once.

Is anything close to this possible? Maybe with scripting directories?

```
Public ScrapingCancelled As Boolean
Public IE As Object
Public WS As Worksheet
Public RegEx As New RegExp
Public Company As String, Address As String, Phone As String, Email As String, Website As String
Public resultCounter As Long

Public Sub ClearGlobals()

ScrapingCancelled = False

Set IE = Nothing
Set WS = Nothing
Set RegEx = Nothing

ClearOutputVariables

resultCounter = 1

End Sub

Public Sub ClearOutputVariables()

Company = vbNullString
Address = vbNullString
Phone = vbNullString
Email = vbNullString
Website = vbNullString

End Sub


Public Sub PrintResults()

Dim results As Variant 'not string because of phone numbers - they are converted from string to long in variant array

results = Array(Company, Address, Phone, Email, Website)

With WS
    Range(.Cells(resultCounter, 1), .Cells(resultCounter, UBound(results) + 1)).Value2 = results
End With

ClearOutputVariables

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a good place for a user `Type` or custom `Class` as opposed to module level variables.

Comment: As @Comintern mentioned, I would use a `Class` for this. Within your `Class`, you can use `Class_Initialize` and `Class_Terminate` to set these up